# Oversized \underbrace's label causes unwanted spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Consider this:

```
\left( x-1 \right) \underbrace{ \left( ? \right) }_{ \text{what is this?} }
```

The label is longer than the braced portion, which causes unwanted space between the parentheses.

Is there a way around that, so that the parentheses "touch" as they would normally?

Please note that I just started on LaTeX, and I'm using TexMaths inside LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `mathtools` package (which loads and extends the `amsmath` package) provides the command `\mathclap`

[image]

If you decided to change the justification, you could use `\mathllap`

[image]

or `\mathrlap`

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    \left( x-1 \right) \underbrace{ \left( ? \right) }_{ \mathclap{\text{what is this?}} }
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can place the content "what is this?" in a box of smaller width in order to remove this spacing problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\[
  \left( x-1 \right) \underbrace{ \left( ? \right) }_{\text{\makebox[0pt]{what is this?} }}
\]
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

In the above example, "what is this?" is placed in a zero-width box. You can modify this to suit your needs. For example, in this instance, since there's nothing else in the expression, it's fine. However, with other elements it may be required to have some space around "what is this?". Then some negative whitespace (or skipping) might also be useful.

Comment: Very good alternative. Especially when mathtools is not working :)

Comment: This is very nice, but changes the text size.  Here's a slight modification to preserve the text size closer to the underbrace version.
`\underbrace{ (?) }_{\makebox[0pt]{\text{{\scriptsize what is this?}}}}`

Comment: Excellent!!! :)