# operatorname and mathbin spacing

Tags: spacing, math-operators

It seems like operators (e.g. `\sin`) don't mix nicely with binary operations (e.g. `\circ`). An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\sin \circ f$

$\mathrm{sin} \circ f$

$\operatorname{thing} \mathbin{a} f$

$\mathrm{thing} \mathbin{a} f$

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

I want the spacing for the `\operatorname` to be as it is for the `mathrm` (of course I don't want to actually change the `operatorname` to a `mathrm`). How can I achieve this?

Comment: In cases like these, use `{\sin}\circ f`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the same as in [Underbrace changing spacing of operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223908/underbrace-changing-spacing-of-operators), because `\underbrace` creates an Op atom just like `\sin`.

The solution is to use

```
${\sin}\circ f$
```

in this case, because the braces make a subformula, which is considered as an ordinary atom.