# Underbrace messing with horizontal spacing

Tags: underbrace

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{equation*}
\left( 0, \ldots, \underbrace{e_j}_\text{$i$-th postion}, \ldots, 0 \right)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

The problem is that I followed Steven B. Segletes' solution in [Underbrace changing spacing of operators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223908/underbrace-changing-spacing-of-operators) in order to prevent the underbrace text from messing with the horizontal spacing of the surrounding ldots.  Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

And I'd also like the parentheses to ignore the underbrace text with regards to automatic vertical sizing; I'm not sure if I should put that in a separate question because I'm new to the site!

Comment: The issue is that the `_\text{$i$-th postion}` increases the space around `e_j` so if you only type `_\text{i}` for instance, you have less horizontal spacing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose one of these solutions, more elegant  from my  point of view, than an oversized  `\underbrace`. They're based respectively on the `\underbracket` command  from `mathtools`, or on the `\bclap` command from `stackengine`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\bigl( 0, \ldots,  \underbracket[0.4pt]{e_j}_{\clap{\scriptsize$i$-th position}}, \ldots, 0 \bigr)\vspace*{3ex}
\end{equation*}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. 
\begin{equation*}
\bigl( 0, \ldots, e_{\stackMath\bclap{\substack{\boldsymbol{\vert}\\\text{\scriptsize $ i $-th position}}}j}, \ldots, 0 \bigr)
\end{equation*}
Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed elegant; and it answers the question I forgot to ask of how to replace the underbrace with an arrow. :)  Fantastic answer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind appreciation. I've simplified the code of the first solution, as the exterior parentheses size depends no more of a`\left...`right` pair. No more smashing required.

Answer (score 6):

The solution you proposed [links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46311/141947) towards what you need.

See the code below with the corrections to get what you need (corrected horizontal spacing + setup of parentheses)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left( 0, \ldots, \underbrace{e_j}_\text{$i$-th postion}, \ldots, 0 \right)
\end{equation*}
% Corrects spacing issue
\begin{equation*}
\left( 0, \ldots, \underbrace{e_j}_{\mathclap{\text{$i$-th postion}}}, \ldots, 0 \right)
\end{equation*}
% Manual set up of parentheses
\begin{equation*}
\bigl( 0, \ldots, \underbrace{e_j}_{\mathclap{\text{$i$-th postion}}}, \ldots, 0 \bigr)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic!  Thanks so much.  I wish there a way to still use \left( \right) and somehow tell it autoscale but ignore a certain part.

Comment: +1 for `\mathclap` wich emiminates text width. The second issue would equaly be fixed by using also `\smash` which  suppresses the text height ?!

Comment: All the credit goes to cmhughes !