# Automatically correcting underbrace spacing

Tags: spacing, macros, delimiters, underbrace

I would like to define a command to automatize https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503610/128042, since many LaTeX-users don't like the spacing of `\underbrace` (see [using underbrace without having left( and right) scale](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23161/128042), [How to prevent an underbrace, with a subscript, from affecting the sizes of delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435697/how-to-prevent-an-underbrace-with-a-subscript-from-affecting-the-sizes-of-deli/503610#503610), [Underbrace messing with horizontal spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429233/underbrace-messing-with-horizontal-spacing), ...)

I tried the following `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\|}{\|_{2}}
\newcommand{\myVtoken}{}
\newcommand{\myunderbrace}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\myVtoken}{\vphantom{\underbrace{{#1}}_{{#2}}}}%
    \vphantom{#1}\smash[b]{\underbrace{{#1}}_{\mathclap{{#2}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
I would like this to work:
\[
\norm*{\left(2,\myunderbrace{\frac{5}{3}}{\approx 1.66666667\frac{1}{1}} \right)}
\myVtoken %\vphantom{\underbrace{\frac{5}{3}}_{\approx 1.66666667\frac{1}{1}}} %with this \vphantom it would work
\]
The above formula is too close to this line, but this works fine: 
\[
\norm*{\left(2,\smash[b]{\underbrace{\frac{5}{3}}_{\mathclap{\approx 1.66666667}}} \right)}
\vphantom{\underbrace{\frac{5}{3}}_{\approx 1.66666667}}
\]
This text has the correct distance to the line above, because of the vphantom outside of the delimiters.

\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

The `\renewcommand` within the `\newcommand` seems not to work, the way I expected. I tried a bit around with `\let` and `\def`, but I have very litttle knowledge about them.

Does someone know how to redefine a command within a command properly to get the desired effect?

Or are there better solutions to get the desired result, where have an easy to use command where I don't have to copy the content of the `\underbrace` multiple times. I don't want to decide manually how large the delimiters should be using something like `\big`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and straightforward solution is available if one is willing to issue explicit sizing instructions, i.e., `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`, rather than rely on `\left` and `\right` to size the parentheses and norm symbols.

[image]

A non-negligible advantage of the approach taken here is that low-level LaTeX equation placement parameters such as `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip` needn't be tweaked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter and \mathclap macros
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert_2}
\newcommand{\myunderbrace}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\mathclap{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text some text some text some text some text \dots
\[
\norm[\bigg]{\Bigl( 2, \myunderbrace{\frac{5}{3}}{\approx 1.6667} \,\Bigr)}
\]
Some text some text some text some text some text \dots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just I have, only, added after `\begin{document}`,

```
        \abovedisplayskip=0.6cm
        \abovedisplayshortskip=-0.3cm
        \belowdisplayskip=0.6cm
        \belowdisplayshortskip=0.2cm
```

after to have modificated the parameters of the code that you can find into this [link](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=4993).

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\|}{\|_{2}}
\newcommand{\myVtoken}{}
\newcommand{\myunderbrace}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\myVtoken}{\vphantom{\underbrace{{#1}}_{{#2}}}}%
    \vphantom{#1}\smash[b]{\underbrace{{#1}}_{\mathclap{{#2}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
I would like this to work:
\abovedisplayskip=0.6cm
\abovedisplayshortskip=-0.3cm
\belowdisplayskip=0.6cm
\belowdisplayshortskip=0.2cm
\[
\norm*{\left(2,\myunderbrace{\frac{5}{3}}{\approx 1.66666667\frac{1}{1}} \right)}
\myVtoken %\vphantom{\underbrace{\frac{5}{3}}_{\approx 1.66666667\frac{1}{1}}} %with this \vphantom it would work
\]

The above formula is too close to this line, but this works fine: 
\[
\norm*{\left(2,\smash[b]{\underbrace{\frac{5}{3}}_{\mathclap{\approx 1.66666667}}} \right)}
\vphantom{\underbrace{\frac{5}{3}}_{\approx 1.66666667}}
\]
This text has the correct distance to the line above, because of the vphantom outside of the delimiters.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Based on what have you chosen the numbers? Is there a possibility to do this without using explicit numbers, as these numbers are probably different for different journals and styles. In this solution `\myVtoken` could be dropped as it would not be needed and does not have any effect here.

Comment: for very large stuff under the underbrace, this solution does not work :(

Comment: @Jakob I have chosen the numbers in function to the blank space between above and below formula;  I have done several compilations to have an adapt space.