# I want a really small underbrace

Tags: math-mode, spacing

This question is related to, but distinct from [Oversized \underbrace's label causes unwanted spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46308/oversized-underbraces-label-causes-unwanted-spacing).

My issue isn't with the spacing of the label, but with *the size of the underbrace itself*. Using the accepted answer at that page as a reference, I do not like the space around `(?)` caused by the brace underneath it. I would like the left and right vertical limits of the brace to lie *under* the parentheses, not around them.

That is, the brace in that answer could crudely be sketched as

```
 (?)
\---/
```

but I instead would like

```
(?)
\-/
```

(In the case I am actually frustrated with right now, the object is `du` rather than `(?)`, but I think the same reasoning should apply.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even after smashing the label width (the usual culprit as addressed in the linked question), the brace cannot shrink any more because it is the smallest size provided in Computer Modern.

Some font/symbol packages define smaller curly braces. The only one I can think of off the top of my head is `MnSymbol`, which is unfortunate because it has several incompatibilities.

An alternative that should work with any font packages is to define a new `\smallunderbrace` command that uses the smallest font `\tiny` to create the brace:

```
\def\smallunderbrace#1{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \tiny\upbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
```

This command is identical to `\underbrace` from base LaTeX with the exception of `\tiny` inserted in the last line. Here's the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\smallunderbrace#1{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \tiny\upbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  (du) \\
  (\smallunderbrace{du}_{\text{\clap{label}}}) \\
  (\smallunderbrace{\text{test}}_{\text{\clap{label}}})
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

The last test line is just to show that this new command is still extensible, but the `\smallunderbrace` command should only be used when the standard `\underbrace` is too big.

Comment: So this package just redefines braces? There is some other reason I have `MnSymbol` in my preamble already, but I've commented it out temporarily because calling as many packages as I am using makes compilation take a ridiculously long time.

Comment: No, it does [a lot more](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf), which is part of the reason there are many incompatibilities. It changes nearly all the symbols, which may or may not be desirable for your document.

Comment: Whoa. I really like Minion, actually, but I didn't know how to put my document in it, so it's currently in Palatino.

Comment: @jdc see the update. This version should work with whichever math/text fonts you've selected.

Comment: I had some issues with `Misplaced \noalign`, I solved those by wrapping the `\tiny\upbracefill` in curly braces: `{\tiny\upbracefill}` in my definition of `\smallunderbrace`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a minimum size of the underbrace and there's nothing to do with it, unless a different strategy is used:

1. TikZ bracket decorations, that are just awful, in my opinion
2. underbrackets instead of underbraces

The best strategy, however, is to use underbraces in *very rare* occasions.

If you want that the underbrace is slimmer and shorter, you can exploit the fact that `amsmath` defines the math extension font also at a reduced size (I've never understood why Knuth didn't provide cmex5 and cmex7).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\upbracefill}{\m@th}{\scriptstyle\m@th}{}{}
\patchcmd{\upbracefill}{$\braceld$}{$\scriptstyle\braceld$}{}{}
\patchcmd{\upbracefill}{\bracelu}{\bracelu\mkern-1mu}{}{}
\patchcmd{\upbracefill}{\hfill\braceru}{\hfill\mkern-1mu\braceru}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\underbrace{du}_{\text{label}}\\
\underbrace{} \\ % minimum size
\underbrace{loooooooooooong}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

As you'll see in the picture, the minimum size is quite smaller than the standard one and the underbrace is smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You want it like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    \left( x-1 \right) (\underbrace{\text{du}}_{ \mathclap{\text{what is this?}} })
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Close! I want `du` in math mode (`d` is a linear map in this context), but more importantly, and I want the *brace itself* to fit under `du`, so that, for example, the parentheses would not have any inclination to be as far away from `du` as they are in your output.