# I want a really small overbrace

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Related to the question (and accepted answer) at [I want a really small underbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224811/93030), in which the following code is used to define a new `\smallunderbrace` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\smallunderbrace#1{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}% 
   \tiny\upbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\clap}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  (du) \\
  (\smallunderbrace{du}_{\text{\clap{label}}}) \\
  (\smallunderbrace{\text{test}}_{\text{\clap{label}}})
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

The answer (by [Paul Gessler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21344/paul-gessler)) states that the `\smallunderbrace` command is identical to `\underbrace` from base LaTeX with the exception of `\tiny` inserted in the last line.

Can anyone please explain how I can adapt this to define a really small overbrace?

Comment: copy the overbrace definition from latex.ltx and add `\tiny` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By similarly adding a `\tiny` to the definition of `\overbrace` =).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\smalloverbrace#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
  \tiny\downbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\clap}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  (du) \\
  (\smalloverbrace{du}^{\text{\clap{label}}}) \\
  (\smalloverbrace{\text{test}}^{\text{\clap{label}}})
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

P.S. There are (at least) five ways to find out how a macro is defined.
(Something about teaching a man how to fish.)

### 1. By using (la)texdef

I don't know if you are a terminal user, but if you are this is a great option. (I think it also works in the command prompt on Windows. Can someone confirm this?)

In a terminal window, type `latexdef <macro name>` (without a slash), so in this case that'd be `latexdef overbrace` in this case. This will show you how the macro is defined.
If you want to know the definition when certain packages or classes are loaded, you can tell latexdef using `-p [<options]<package>` flag and `-c [<options>]<class>` respectively.

Here's an example:

`latexdef -c book -p amsmath -p [draft]hyperref chapter`

*(`amsmath`, and `hyperref` don't actually change the definition of `\chapter`, but I couldn't think of a good example on the fly.)*

For more info on `latexdef`, type `latexdef -h`, or see the documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdef?lang=en). You may need to use `texdef -t latex` instead of `latexdef`.

### 2. By using `\show`

Somewhere in your document, add the following code:

```
\show\overbrace
```

When you now run LaTeX it will stop to show you the definition of `\overbrace`. You can also check the output or the .log file if you are running in nonstopmode.

### 3. By using `\meaning`

Somewhere in your document, add the following:

```
\texttt{\meaning\overbrace}
```

This will put the definition of `\overbrace` right in your document. It will look awful without the `\texttt` because backslashes aren't typeset correctly (unless you use `fontenc`).

### 4. By looking at the documentation

You can look at the documentation if you know the package or class in which a macro is defined. To quickly see the documentation for something TeX-related, you can use texdoc: either type `texdoc <query>` in a terminal or use [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/). Examples: `texdoc texdef` (`texdoc latexdef` doesn't work), `texdoc hyperref`, `texdoc symbols-a4` or `texdoc texdoc`).

The documentation often (but not always) includes the source code. To figure out where a macro is defined you can add the `-f` flag to `latexdef` (from method 1). For the documentation on the LaTeX source code, search for `source2e`.

### 5. By looking up the .sty/.cls file for the relevant package/class

You can look directly at the source if you know the package or class in which a macro is defined. This can be faster if many definitions are nested and may also be useful because the original code for long definitions is often spread out over multiple lines and indented (and on occasion includes comments).

To figure out where a macro is defined you can add the `-f` flag to `latexdef` (from method 1). If `latexdef` says that a macro is defined by LaTeX then it can probably be found in latex.ltx, in fontmath.ltx, or in one of the other files in the same directory. Where all of these files are located may depend on your TeX distribution and/or OS. To find out where a particular file is, you can type `kpsewhich <filename.sty/cls>` or `kpsewhich <latex.ltx/fontmath.ltx>` (again, in a terminal). (And I again think that should also work in Windows, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Thank you! More fundamentally, then, how do I find out the definition of a given command? (I did try to answer this question beforehand - promise!)

Comment: Good point, that'd probably be more useful to know than just how handle this particular case.

Comment: May have gotten a little carried away >_>

Comment: This is just brilliantly helpful - thank you so much! :)

Comment: For completeness, here's the code for a similar \smallunderbrace{} command.  `\def\smallunderbrace#1{\mathop {\vtop {\m@th \ialign {##\crcr $\hfil \displaystyle {#1}\hfil $\crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ \nointerlineskip }
\tiny\upbracefill \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ }}}}\limits}
\makeatother`