# How to draw an arrow diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to draw a diagram like this. Is this possible to do with Ti*k*Z? I read the tutorial, but didn't see anything specifically for this. I am also not sure how to describe what I want to draw either.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, please show us what you have tried so far. Because, this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Comment: @Raaja I am sorry if my question came across as a "just do it for me" type of question. I was trying to phrase it as a "point me in a direction to get started".

Comment: @Evan Kim To start, you can always start with a simple figure from TikZ manual and try to build something close to what you want and then ask how to modify `X` to achieve `Y` :) or please explicitly mention such a statement as in your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need Ti*k*Z for that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419690/156344
\def\smalloverbrace#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
  \tiny\downbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[\smalloverbrace{1}^{\mathclap{\text{identity}}},\underbrace{(12),(13),(23),}_{\mathclap{\text{three transpositions}}}\overbrace{(123),(132)}^{\mathclap{\text{two 3-cycles}}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 3:** I replaced everything because there were a few commas missing or deleting from the code and brackets.

As already written by the very good @JouleV user, there is no need to use graphics to create simple graphics that can be traced back to commutative diagrams, or to simple tricks of symbolic mathematical notation. I'm showing you another possibility that certainly won't be the best.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=.4cm, column sep=.2cm]
& 1, &  \underbrace{{(12), (13), (23)}}{}, & \underbrace{{(123), (132)}}{} \arrow[rd, no head] &  \\
\text{identity}  \arrow[ru] &   & \text{three traspositions} 
\arrow[u, no head] &  &\text{two 3--cycles} 
\end{tikzcd}   
\end{document}
```