# Wrapping text with mathclap

Tags: mathtools

How can I wrap the text from `\mathclap` so that the text doesn't spill over like the picture?

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419690/156344
\def\smalloverbrace#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
  \tiny\downbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \[ \mu = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx} = \underbrace{\bar{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{x-coordinate of centroid of region $\mathcal{R}$ under the graph}}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's the vertical alignment you are concerned about, you could add some height by including a `\vphantom{$\bigg|$}` in the limit text.  (Adjust the "bigness" as necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see, if the following simplified solution is close to what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\mu = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx
    = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx}
    = \underbrace{\bar{x}\strut}_{\mathclap{\begin{smallmatrix}
                            x$-coordinate of$\\
                              $centroid of region$\\
                              \mathcal{R} $ under the graph$
                            \end{smallmatrix}{}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]

Comment: What is the strut for?

Comment: @EvanKim, with it is pushed brace under `\bar{x}` a bit lower (on the position if you instead `x` have `y`). you can observe difference, if you delete it.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\makeatletter% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419690/156344
\def\smalloverbrace#1{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
  \tiny\downbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \[ \mu = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx} = \underbrace{\bar{x}}_{\strut\clap{\scriptsize\Shortunderstack{ x-coordinate of centroid of \\ region $\mathcal{R}$ under the graph}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]