# \underbrace vs. \undercbrace with mtpro2 package

Tags: math-mode, mtpro, underbrace

Please consider the following two-row expression, which uses two instances of `\underbrace` in the first row and two instances of `\undercbrace` (provided by the `mtpro2` package) in the second:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,lite]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,newtxtext,mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{split}
\psi(t) &= \underbrace{a+b+c+d+e}_{f}  + \underbrace{h}_{g} \\
        &= \undercbrace{a+b+c+d+e}_{f} + \undercbrace{h}_{g}
\end{split} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Observe that the minimum width of `\underbrace` can easily exceed the actual width of its first argument. In contrast, the minimum width of the underbraces produced by `\undercbrace` is not all that large. (I believe the `c` in `\undercbrace` stands for either "curly" or "curvy".)

Question: Is it possible to obtain a narrow-width underbrace *without* using mtpro2's `\undercbrace` macro?

Comment: Please check if my edit is satisfactory to you -- or if I completely missed the issue you're looking to fix.

Comment: @Mico Perfect!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want a really small underbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224805/i-want-a-really-small-underbrace)

Comment: @campa Kind campa no :-( I wanted that when I have a few letters the bracket is not curved but horizontal as in the image. In the link you sent me, the curly brackets are too curved. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: OK, sorry, vote retracted. You might want to update the question.