# Stretching of text beyond underbrace

Tags: pdftex

The current behavior when using `\underbrace` is the following (Tex inserts whitespace to avoid streching the text underneath the underbrace beneith the neighboring symbols):
[image]

The behavior I want instead is the following:
[image]

How can this be achieved?

EDIT: The code I used for this image is  as follows

```
Y_{2,2}(\theta,\varphi) - Y_{2,-2}(\theta,\varphi) = \dfrac{2i}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\sqrt{\dfrac{15}{8}} \underbrace{\sin^2\theta\sin(2\varphi)}_{=\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\theta\sin\varphi\cos\varphi={\frac{1}{2}d_{xy}/C_{xy}}}
```

Comment: Hi! It would be nice if you provided the code you used to generate the top image so that we don't have to type it all out for you. You'll get your answer more quickly that way! :)

Comment: ok, sure. Done! :)

Comment: Thanks! :) While you were doing that, I found this, does it help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46308/oversized-underbraces-label-causes-unwanted-spacing

Comment: Isn't it `Υ` (Upsilon) rather than `Y`?

Comment: @Bernard I thought so too at first, but then I assumed it was probably the font, especially as it's an italic upper-case letter

Comment: Yet  the curved upper part… Anyway, I'm probably too pernickety, and that is not the main problem.

Comment: The only embarrassing thing is that I didn't notice in time that the double angle relation is wrong and should be `\sin(2\varphi)=2\sin\varphi\cos\varphi`  instead. It's an `Y`, the display is due to the font...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want? Using `\mathclap` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  Y_{2, 2}(\theta, \varphi) - Y_{2, -2}(\theta, \varphi) =
  \frac{2i}{\sqrt{4\pi}} \sqrt{\dfrac{15}{8}}
  \underbrace{\sin^{2}\theta \sin(2\varphi)}_{\mathclap{= \frac{1}{2}
    \sin^{2}\theta \sin\varphi \cos\varphi = \frac{1}{2}d_{xy}/C_{xy}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes `mathtools` seems to provide some really helpful macros. Didn't know about this before.

Comment: @SimonFromme Good good :) Glad to be of help. Hope you don't mind, but I've marked this question as duplicate to keep the site nice and tidy

Answer (score 4):

Use `\mathclap`from `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case), and  possibly `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \Upsilon_{2,2}(\theta,\varphi) - \Upsilon_{2,-2}(\theta,\varphi) = \dfrac{2i}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\sqrt{\dfrac{15}{8}} \underbrace{\sin^2\theta\sin(2\varphi)}_{\mathclap{=\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\theta\sin\varphi\cos\varphi = {\frac{1}{2}d_{xy}/C_{xy}}}} \]

\vspace{4ex}
\[ \Upsilon_{2,2}(\theta,\varphi) - \Upsilon_{2,-2}(\theta,\varphi) = \dfrac{2i}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\sqrt{\dfrac{15}{8}} \underbrace{\sin^2\theta\sin(2\varphi)}_{\substack{\mathclap{=\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\theta\sin\varphi \cos\varphi}\\=\frac{1}{2}d_{xy}/C_{xy}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\shortstack` is a nice idea

Comment: @Mico: Thank you for pointing all these problems. `\shortstack` was an initial version, and I forgot to change the phrasing. All is (hopefully) fixed now.